# Can someone help me find a solution to error source in my code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor, named-entity-recognition

I am training a BI-LSTM-CRF model for a NER task. I was able to build the model, but when I fit it with the training data, googlecolab throw me an error.

Here is the code for my model below (or here : [code for my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En3QK.png)):

```
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(MAX_SENTENCE,))

model = layers.Embedding(WORD_COUNT, DENSE_EMBEDDING, embeddings_initializer="uniform", input_length=MAX_SENTENCE)(input_layer)

model = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(LSTM_UNITS, recurrent_dropout=LSTM_DROPOUT, return_sequences=True))(model)

model = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(DENSE_UNITS, activation="relu"))(model)

crf_layer = CRF(units=TAG_COUNT)

output_layer = crf_layer(model)

ner_model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)

loss = losses.crf_loss

acc_metric = metrics.crf_accuracy

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

ner_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=[acc_metric])

ner_model.summary()
```

Then after fitting the model, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history' ([error message for google colab][2])
```

Here is the list of my dependencies :[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GxvR.png)

**Can someone help me out?**

Comment: The title is not the best. Everyone asking a question here is looking for a solution related to programming. Make your title specific to your question to draw more attention.

Comment: Ok, Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what module you're using because you didn't provide any but I'm guessing that's `tensorflow`. Try using lower versions of Python like `Python 3.7` and also try installing a specific and compatible version: `pip install tensorflow==1.13.1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Indeed I am using TensorFlow . I've already tried to downgrade TensorFlow version, but it didn't work .

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you have more than 1 Python version? If so, make sure that the module is installed in the compatible version and you're using the compatible version